# Google Sheets IF Statement

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

Thank you to those who have helped me on this project so far. My issue now is I need to have my data return in this format.

I have this formula working to look for "H" and "V" then return the names of the employees. I am trying to add an (H) after the name, if an H is present in the cell.

If cell value = "H" return format like this     Employee1(H), Employee2

If Cell value is not H return value like this    Employee1,

This is the formula I have that is working to return the names

```
=IFNA(JOIN(", ", FILTER(Input!$A$5:$A$30, REGEXMATCH(Input!Q5:Q30, "V|H"))))
```

This is the IF logic I have but it is not inputting the (H) after the name, it is still just returning the names so the IF I have is False

```
=IFNA( IF (Input!K5:K30 = "H", JOIN( " (H) , ", FILTER (Input!$A$5:$A$30, Input!K5:K="H")), JOIN(", ", FILTER(Input!$A$5:$A$30, REGEXMATCH(Input!K5:K30, "V")))))
```

The formula above is what is in the sheet I realized I still had the V|H in but when removed it still didn't work

Due to this being on a company system I can only share this file with someone if I have an email address to share with, it will not let me get a public link to share with anyone.

Here is the link but I am not sure if it will work so if it will not please send me your email and I will add to the file for access.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c-KYphQwpMuT2IK9ezHms4DqbyL0fjgSksPFwBhLJXU/edit?usp=sharing

ScreenShots
[image: Input]
[image: Calendar]

Comment: Thank you, I have sent you a link to your posted contact email on your profile. Also I have added the formula you suggested to E5-H5 (Or January 1-4th) on the Calendar, the names show but no (H) yet.

Comment: you forgot `Input!` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYw76.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IFNA(JOIN(", ", FILTER(IF(Input!Q5:Q30="H", Input!A5:A30&"(H)", Input!A5:A30), 
 REGEXMATCH(Input!Q5:Q30, "V|H"))))
```

[image: 0]